# JavaScript within HTML not executing

Tags: javascript, html

I've recently begun learning HTML and JavaScript and am in the process of creating a simple video rental script in Notepad++. After creating the script, it fails to execute locally in any browser. I am curious as to what parts may have been improperly used or if I am missing something entirely, thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var name = window.prompt("Hello, what is your name?");
    var choice = window.prompt("DVD or Blu-Ray?");
    var days = parseInt(window.prompt("How many days are you renting for?"));


    if (choice == "DVD") {
      double dvdcst = 2.99;
      double dvdtot = dvdcst * days;
      document.write("Name: " + name "<br />"
        "Days renting: " + days + "<br />"
        "Cost per day: " + dvdcst + "<br />"
        "Total cost: " + dvdtot + "<br />");
    } else if (choice == "Blu-Ray") {
      double blucst = 3.99;
      double blutot = blucst * days;
      document.write("Name: " + name + "<br />"
        "Days renting: " + days + "<br />"
        "Cost per day: " + blucst + "<br />"
        "Total cost: " + blutot + "<br />");
    }
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and **read the error message**.

Comment: Not sure what the canonical dupe is, but the problem is you have to use the `+` at the end of each line to continue the string. So `"Days renting: " + days + "<br />"` becomes `"Days renting: " + days + "<br />" + `

Comment: Unrelated, but may be helpful. `dvdcst * days` and `blucst * days` may give non money formatted results such as `6.1` instead of `6.10`.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few missing `+`'s. You forgot one when adding `name` and `"<br />"` on line 20 and then, when formatting with new lines, you need to use pluses as well.

Also, `double` is not a thing that exists in Javascript. You can define variables using only `var` (for local scope) or with no prefix.

Try the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>

    </head>

    <body>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var name = window.prompt("Hello, what is your name?");
            var choice = window.prompt("DVD or Blu-Ray?");
            var days = parseInt(window.prompt("How many days are you renting for?"));


            if (choice == "DVD")
            {
                dvdcst = 2.99;
                dvdtot = dvdcst * days;
                document.write("Name: " + name + "<br />"+
                "Days renting: " + days + "<br />"+
                "Cost per day: " + dvdcst + "<br />"+
                "Total cost: " + dvdtot + "<br />");
            }

            else if (choice == "Blu-Ray")
            {
                blucst = 3.99;
                blutot =  blucst * days;
                document.write("Name: " + name + "<br />"+
                "Days renting: " + days + "<br />"+
                "Cost per day: " + blucst + "<br />"+
                "Total cost: " + blutot + "<br />");
            }


        </script>


   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also note that you removed the "double" type's from the variables.

Comment: Yes, true, will explain.